# Send sms via Twilio with url

Tags: c#, sms, twilio

I'm using twilio to send SMS messages.

In the message I have an URL but instead of showing the entire URL (which works) I want something like "Click here" which is the URL.

To clarify:

What my SMS is now:
Follow this link: http://www.someurl.com

What I want:
**Click here** to ...

Where "Click here" is the url i.e. http://www.someurl.com

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Since there is no such thing as "markup" in an SMS, there is no way to create HTML-style hyperlinks.  The fact that a string of characters in the SMS message is recognized and becomes a hyperlink is completely dependent upon the device having that capability.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

As Devin says, you can't, SMS messages are pure text, not html. What you could do is use an off-the-shelf, or custom, url shortener (i.e.. bit.ly) if you want the urls to either be shorter, or personalized.